# Strange result after readMetadata() call

Tags: metadata-api, xml

I'm noticing a strange behaviour in the Metadata API's readMetadata() method which affects my custom implementation. Please, find below screen shots describing the issue. I hope somebody can help me with this.

Layout properties one:

[image]

Response from readMetadata() call:

[image]

Layout properties two:

[image]

Response from readMetadata() call:

[image]

As you can see from the screen shots, in the second configuration the `runAssignmentRulesDefault` flag is not present in the response xml. Is this a normal behaviour or a flaw in the method's logic? Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The XML data is technically correct, while the UI is technically incorrect. If "default" is set, but the box isn't shown, no assignment should occur when creating/updating a lead/case record. You may want to submit a case for this if it matters. In either case, the assignment rules should not trigger if the box is not shown, because the user has no chance to modify the behavior (by checking or unchecking the box).

Comment: sfdcfox, thanks for the quick replay. My understanding is that if 'default' is set, assignment rules should trigger no matter if the box is present or not. It seems I get it wrong. :)

Comment: @vortex If that's true, that's a relatively new feature. As far as I've known, you can't force the use of assignment rules in the UI without Visualforce.

Comment: I have a custom VF page in which I want to control wheather to trigger or not the default assignment rule, based on that flag. No matter if the checkbox is present or not. I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @vortex I could see how that'd be a problem. I think you might need to contact support. If the behavior is as I think it is, then I'm right, but if not, then there's a bug in the metadata API that needs logging. It wouldn't be the first bug someone's found this release.